# Adding Custom Date Format to JSP html code

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

`<td>${item.actionDate}</td>` receives a date in format of 2019-11-17 (yyyy/mm/dd). I want to edit this format into dd/mm/yyyy. I found out that I can give format to this td element by using below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#serial_no_date_format').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
   })
</script>
```

I know that above code snip is correct because it is working in other part of my code. However, I could not pass this date format to my td.item.actionDate element with id reference.

My whole is below

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_1_1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover order-column">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sevkiyat No</th>
                            <th>Operator</th>
                            <th>İşlem Tarihi</th>
                            <th>İşlem</th>
                            <th>Lokasyon</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${shipmentTransferHistoryList}" var="item">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${item.shipmentDetailId}</td>
                                <td>${item.operator}</td>
                                <td>${item.actionDate} id="serial_no_date_format"</td>
                                <td>${item.shipmentStatus.alias}</td>
                                <td>${item.actionLocation}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#serial_no_date_format').datepicker({
                                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                            });
                        })
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id should be setted inside the tag.

```
<td>${item.actionDate} id="serial_no_date_format"</td>
```

Change to this

```
<td id="serial_no_date_format">${item.actionDate} </td>
```

Be aware that you can have problems with repeated id so if possible change it to class.

**EDIT**

I think this gonna solve your problem.

```
var date = $('#serial_no_date_format').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}).val();
$('#serial_no_date_format').val(date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not giving any errors now but it is still not applying date format. Do you have any idea about that?